# Invoke WCF proxy using message contract objects

Tags: c#, wcf

When generating a WCF client proxy using SvcUtil.exe, the generated code contains classes that represent the message contracts (e.g. ImportDocument & ImportDocument_Result).

How can I invoke WCF operations by sending an object of such a class as a request to the endpoint, without having to call into the operation method and supplying all parameters?

So instead of

```
var proxy = new WebService_PortClient("endpointConfigurationName");
string result = proxy.ImportDocument("aNumber", "aLocation", "aType", "aDescription");
```

I would like to:

```
 var proxy = new WebService_PortClient("endpointConfigurationName");
 ImportDocument request = new ImportDocument
 {
     Number = "aNumber",
     Location = "aLocation",
     Type = "aType",
     Description = "aDescription"
 };

var response = (ImportDocument_Result)proxy.Invoke(request);
string result = response.return_value;
```

The code above uses an Invoke method, but that method does not exist. Is there an available equivalent to such an Invoke method?

Comment: if configured , `WCF` services exchange `MessageContract`s only.